# GWT : Set tree widget width

Tags: css, gwt, tree, smartgwt

I have added a custom TreeItem to the tree.The TreeItem has a horizontal panel whose bottom-border width is 1px height,to make it to look like a table row(So basically i want to make the tree look like tree table). But the problem is, the tree width is confined by its content.I'm unable to increase the tree width to make it look like table.I tried increasing the width of horizontal panel present in the tree item,but that doesn't work.Can anyone please help me on this?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.gwt-Tree table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.gwt-Tree table td:first-child {
    width: 18px;
}
```

Comment: is that GWT default styling?.

Comment: No, this is not default styling. This is what I use to make each TreeItem span the entire width available to a Tree.

Comment: I want the entire tree width to set according to the screen size.But i'm unable to set the tree width.

Comment: A Tree always takes as much space as is available because it is build in a `div` - a block element. You must be doing something to your Tree to make it narrower.

Comment: This style is applied to a table inside a div with a `gwt-Tree` class name - just like the CSS selector indicates. You don't have to add it manually to anything - just add this rule to your CSS file.

Comment: So we need to add this CSS rule and also we need to programmatically add style to tree? like tree.addStyleName("table").Sorry, still i don't get, how will your css work.

Comment: I can use that style in my UIbinder? within <Ui:Style></Ui:Style>?

Comment: As I said already, you don't have to add any styles to a tree widget. Simply add this rule to your CSS file.

Comment: i tried adding.But it doesn't work! still my tree width is confined to its content width.!.Width is not increasing!

Comment: This means you do something else with your Tree. Most likely, you set some style on your Tree which causes this problem.

Comment: I add widget to TreeItem.i.e i had HorizontalPanel(which has 2 label in it) to the TreeItem.When i set the horizontalpanel width in "px", my tree width is changing according to that.

Comment: No, your Tree width is 100%, because it's a `div`. Your TreeItem width changes according to the width of your HorizontalPanel. Examine your Tree in Chrome or Firefox. Look for a div with class "gwt-Tree" - this is your Tree.

Comment: The css you gave works!. But non-leaf nodes are displayed in a strange way!! that is, the space between the collapsable icon and the non-leaf node name is more!!.Leaf nodes are displayed correctly.

Comment: Can i add the styles you mentioned in the uibinder instead of css file?.i mean between <ui:style> tag?